# HTML/Javascript Access EXIF data before file upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file-upload, exif

I am trying to extract **EXIF** data from a image(jpeg) which has been dragged into the browser or has been selected via a html file input element.

I managed to preview the image within the browser using `FileReader and FileReader.readAsDataURL`
as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader).

and I found a [EXIF library](http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/05/reading-exif-data-with-javascript.html) which allows to extract the EXIF data of an image via javascript. But for me it only works if I use it with normal `img` tags which load their content over a URL.

I also found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784459/javascript-can-i-read-exif-data-from-a-file-upload-input) on StackOverflow where the accepted answer states that it is just not possible.

But I am pretty sure that it can be realized because [500px.com](http://500px.com) extracts the EXIF data immediately after a file is added for upload and before the upload has been finished.

Some ideas how it should be possible to extract the EXIF data from the base64 encoded image I get from the FileReader?

Comment: a newer solution [exif-js](https://github.com/jseidelin/exif-js), based on the same [EXIF_ Library](http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/05/reading-exif-data-with-javascript.html) from [http://www.nihilogic.dk/](http://www.nihilogic.dk/)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I finally found a client side solution for the problem:

1. Read the file using the `FileReader` and the method `.readAsBinaryString`
2. Then wrap that binary string into a BinaryFile object which is already included in the [EXIF Library](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js)
3. Finally call `EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(binaryFileObject);`

and its done :)

Comment: Trying to include binaryajax.js in my project causes an access denied error, so this is not a solution for me.

Comment: The link to nihilogic.dk is dead.

Comment: Links to BinaryFile object and EXIF Library are also dead.

Comment: If you want to use exif-js, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981555/retrieve-exif-image-meta-data-from-html5-fileapi-loaded-image#answer-40076913 – it does the trick pretty simple.

Comment: This code will work without creating an <img> tag:

`const fr = new FileReader();`

`fr.onload = () => {`

`const result = exif.readFromBinaryFile(fr.result);`

`};`

`fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);` "file" is an instance of "File" class

Answer (score 4):

**[jQuery-fileExif](https://github.com/sanisoft/jQuery-fileExif)** javascript library reads image exif data before upload.
[GitHub link](https://github.com/sanisoft/jQuery-fileExif), example [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/noonon/Ls5Dw/) from the library.

```
var someCallback = function(exifObject) {

    $('#cameraModel').val(exifObject.Model);
    $('#lat').val(exifObject.GPSLatitude);
    $('#lng').val(exifObject.GPSLongitude);
    // Uncomment the line below to examine the
    // EXIF object in console to read other values
    //console.log(exifObject);

  }

      try {
        $('#file').change(function() {
            $(this).fileExif(someCallback);
        });
      }
      catch (e) {
        alert(e);
      }
```

Comment: I get Access Denied in jquery simply trying to include the library in my project.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the code of the [**FxIF firefox extension**](http://code.google.com/p/fxif/). It reads exif data using only JavaScript. To read the file contents, you can use the [**FileReader API**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/FileReader) of modern browsers.

Comment: I really want to avoid browser extensions. As i mentioned i am already using FileReady but I don't know how to extract the EXIF data from the data I get from FileReader

Answer (score 0):

When you get your File class instance via the file input, do this:

```
import exif from 'exif-js';

const fr = new FileReader();

fr.onload = () => {
  const result = exif.readFromBinaryFile(fr.result);
  //    ^ EXIF data will be here
};

fr.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
```