# How can I detect image specs clientside with javascript

Tags: javascript, validation

I want to validate image file uploads client side.
T
here will be server side validation, too, which is working already with image magick.

I would like to reproduce this on the client side before uploading (since the files will be quite large and prerequisits for the image files are very restricted, it could save the user much pain if the validation takes place in the browser before the upload process)

Allowed files would be:

- JPEG
- EPS
- TIFF

I need to detect:

- Color Space (CMYK / RGB)
- Size (width x height) // this one is easy - on JPEGs, but how about TIFF and EPS?
- Resolution (dpi)

The main problem is detecting color space and handling the non-JPG formats. Is there something like ImageMagick's "identify" for javascript or do you have any other ideas...?!

Comment: May be helpful - [wiki page for image support in browsers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support). To get all the support you want, you may need to write code to parse the metadata of these files, and read them with _FileReader_

Comment: http://blog.rrikesh.com/demo/jquery-exif.html

Comment: So... Could you please provide some code or explain what you have already tried? Questions asking for code should provide samples of the work accomplished, what has been tried, what didn't work and the final goal.

Comment: I'm actually in [the early stages of tackling this sort of thing (with client-side javascript) myself](https://github.com/rnicholus/determinater).  Currently, I'm only working on identifying file types by examining magic bytes in a given file as that can be accomplished quite efficiently.  I may expand this to identify other aspects of specific files, such as image dimensions, but determining that sort of thing is a bit more resource intensive as the entire file may have to be read client-side.  We are also quite limited as to the types of image files we can examine client-side.

Comment: ...another option (to gather some of the other info your have asked for) is to ready exif data client-side, as @loops pointed out.  That is also certainly doable via javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341685/html-javascript-acces-exif-data-before-file-upload). It uses HTML5 APIs, but it looks like what you are looking for.