# How to extract Color Space from jpg/jpeg image types in Javascript, Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, image, color-space

How to extract colorspace from an image, mostly jpg/jpeg. I've to validate the color space during image uploads on our ReactJS application. I only need to allow submission if the color space is RGB. I'm mostly looking for client-side validation in Javascript. Thank you!

I'm using input tag with type as file for image uploads.

Comment: Have you checked out this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18061324/how-can-i-detect-image-specs-clientside-with-javascript

Comment: @mrrogers Yes, I have implemented what was said in that article for some reason if I upload an image with CYMK color space.EXIF (readFromBinaryFile, getAllTags, pretty) methods are returning empty objects. I'm using https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js

Comment: Sad.  I thought that might give a good hint.  Could you just leverage those failed methods (`readFromBinaryFile` etc) to know that you have a good or bad format?

Comment: @mrrogers Tried that as well but of no use. I ended up [using this library](https://github.com/mattiasw/ExifReader), which solved the problem.

Comment: RGB is nor a colour space. And using RGB colour model to JPEG is negating the main reason of JPEG. EXIF gives different data (and the colour space, like sRGB, adobeRGB or custome one), but the image is not stored (usually) as RGB data