# Retrieve EXIF Image Meta Data from HTML5 FileApi loaded Image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filereader

I am using the HTML5 [File API & FileReader](http://html5demos.com/file-api).

HTML:

```
<div id="holder"></div>
```

JS:

```
<script>
var holder = document.getElementById('holder'),
    state = document.getElementById('status');

if (typeof window.FileReader === 'undefined') {
  state.className = 'fail';
} else {
  state.className = 'success';
  state.innerHTML = 'File API & FileReader available';
}

holder.ondragover = function () { this.className = 'hover'; return false; };
holder.ondragend = function () { this.className = ''; return false; };
holder.ondrop = function (e) {
  this.className = '';
  e.preventDefault();

  var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0],
      reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function (event) {
    console.log(event.target);
    holder.style.background = 'url(' + event.target.result + ') no-repeat center';
  };
  console.log(file);
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);

  return false;
};
</script>
```

**How can I retrieve EXIF meta data from the uploaded image?**

I tried to use [this](http://blog.nihilogic.dk/2008/05/jquery-exif-data-plugin.html).

HTML:

```
<img src="image1.jpg" id="img1" exif="true" />
```

JS:

```
console.log($("#img1").exifPretty());
```

This only returns an empty set.

I also use the [FileReader JQuery Plugin](https://github.com/bgrins/filereader.js).

When I use the load function I get a file which is an extension of the original File object.

```
on:
    load: function(e, file) { }
```

**But how do I retrieve the EXIF meta data from it?**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341685/html-javascript-acces-exif-data-before-file-upload

Comment: @Andreas I use the FileReader JQuery Plugin to retrieve the file: https://github.com/bgrins/filereader.js I have a file object but I cannot manage to get the meta data. See my question update. Can you please post an answer?

Comment: In your example you're not using the FileReader plugin so did you even try the solution of the linked SO question? Use `.readAsBinaryString` from a `FileReader`, wrap this string into a `BinaryFile` (included in `EXIF` lib) feed this object to `EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(binaryFileObject)`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
on:
    load: function(event, file) {
    // get image meta data
    var base64 = event.target.result.replace(/^.*?,/,'');
    var binary = atob(base64);
    var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(new BinaryFile(binary));
}
```

Comment: I dont know why its says "ReferenceError: exif is not defined", even i have added jquery.exif.js.

Comment: I think this answer requires the exif-js dependency, hence the EXIF not defined errors you are receiving: https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js (That said it's not a great answer, check this one instead: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341685/html-javascript-access-exif-data-before-file-upload)

Answer (score 2):

If you're getting EXIF undefined, then use `var EXIF = require('./exif.js');` FTW.

I managed to get that beast working without magic tricks (quick&dirty trial&error result):

```
'use strict';
var EXIF = require('./exif.js');

$(function() {
    $('#fileinput').on('change', function(){
       var files = this.files,
           i=0;
        for(i=0; i<files.length;++i){
            previewImage(this.files[i]);
        }
    });
    function previewImage(file) {
        var gallery = $('#gallery'),
            thumb = null,
            img = null,
            reader= null;
        if(!file.type.match('image/*')){
            throw 'File type must be an image';
        }

        thumb = $('<div />',{class: 'thumbnail'}).appendTo(gallery);
        img = $('<img />');
        reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e){
            img.prop('src',reader.result);
            // important for exif-js! Set src attribute after calling img.prop
            img.src = img.prop('src');
            img.appendTo(thumb);
            EXIF.getData(img, function() {
                console.log(EXIF.pretty(img));
            });
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

with help of exif.js , the following script can get the exif from file input

```
$('#imageupload').change(function(){
    var file = this.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {

        var exif = EXIF.readFromBinaryFile(this.result);
        console.log(exif);


     }

     reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);


});
```