# Is GPS EXIF data available client-side when selecting on an iPhone?

Tags: ios, gps, exif, filereader

I'm using the excellent [jquery.exif.js](http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/exifjquery/) library as per [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10341685/html-javascript-acces-exif-data-before-file-upload).

However, when selecting an image using an iPhone (Safari), on iOS 7.0.4, the `exifObject.GPSLatitude` and and `exifObject.GPSLatitude` fields are not present client-side. By contrast, if I do a traditional full upload sent to the server, GPS EXIF data is correctly present in the image file.

Can anyone point me to a definitive statement as to whether client-side (i.e. FileReader) support for iOS reading GPS EXIF data should work?